# $|2018x_n - x_{n+1}| = 0 \Rightarrow x_n = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let's consider family of seminorms:

$$p_n(x) = |2018x_n - x_{n+1}|$$

where $x_n \in l^\infty$

I want to check whether $(p_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ or $(p_{2n})_{n=1}^\infty$ separate points.

**My work so far**

Starting from $p_n$:

I want to cehck condition: $$|2018x_n - x_{n+1}| = 0 \Rightarrow x_n = 0$$

$$|2018x_n - x_{n+1}| = 0 \Leftrightarrow 2018x_n -x_{n+1} = 0 \Leftrightarrow x_{n+1} = 2018x_n$$

So we have constructed sequence:

$$x_n = (x_1, 2018x_1, 2018^2x_1,...)$$

Now if we fix any $x_1$ we will observe that if go further and further, values of $x_n$ will increase. In other words $\sup_n|x_n| = \infty \Rightarrow|x_n| \notin l^\infty$. So it cannot seperate points in $l^\infty$.

Am I correct? We can make exactly the same argument with sequence $(p_{2n})$

Comment: Actually the family $(p_n)$ _does_ separate points. The fact that $x=(x_1, 2018 x_1,\dots)$ does not quite imply $x\notin\ell_\infty$; in fact if you assume that $x\in\ell_\infty$ it follows that $x=0$, qed.

Comment: But the argument for $(p_{2n})$ doesn't seem the same to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did shows that $p_n(x)=0$ for all $n$ implies ($x_1=0$ and so) $x=0$. Hence $(p_n)$ does separate points. But  $(p_{2n})$ does not separate points. The sequence $(x_n)=(0,1, 2018,0,0,...)$ gives $p_{2n}(x)=0$ for all $n \geq 1$.

Comment: Could you please explain to me why $p_n(x) = 0$ imples that $x_1 = 0$? I completely don't get it. I understand that $p_n(x) = 0$ implies form of $x = (x_1, 2018x_1,...)$. But why $x_1 = 0$?

Comment: Is it because $x \in l^\infty$? And if we take $x_1 \neq 0$ then $x \notin l^\infty$, because supremum would not be bounded?

Comment: Exactly. That is the argument. @Lucian